# Problems with table layout

Tags: tables, siunitx, booktabs, threeparttable

I have some issues when creating my OLS regression in LaTeX and I really hope, that some of you could help me. I have three questions:

1) How to make "Growth 91-92" and "Growth92-93" with a space, so I can see it is a part of the "Growth"-categori.
2) How to make all models (1-5) columns in the same length?
3) How to make the first column a big bigger then the models-columns?

I would like to create a table, which look like this:

[image]
My preamble look like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,calc,threeparttable} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{threeparttable}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.0}
\medskip
\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ @{} p{2.4cm} 
     @{\extracolsep{\fill}}   
     *{10}{S[table-format=2.6]} @{}}
\toprule
& {Model I} & {Model II} & {Model III} & {Model IV} & {Model V} \\
\emph{Afh.\ var.}
& {All partys} & {All partys} & {Social Democrat} & {Liberal} & {Conservative} \\
\midrule
\emph{Uafh.\ var.} \\
Nationalpol. effects & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,11\sym{***}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,22\sym{*}} &  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,33\sym{***}} &  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,44\sym{*}} &  
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,55\sym{***}} &   \\
& 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,11)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,22)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,33)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,44)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,55)} &  \\
Economic growth & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,11} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,22} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,33\sym{***}} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,44} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,55\sym{**}} & \\
&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,11)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,22)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,33)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,44)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{(0,55)} & \\
\cmidrule{1-1}
Adjusted R\textsuperscript{2} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,11} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,22} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,33} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,44} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{0,55} &   \\
N & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{111} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{222} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{333} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{444} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{555} &  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make a few changes to your code.

- Most importantly, don't encase each and every numeric cell in a `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` wrapper. Not only is it not necessary to do this, it's counterproductive: the wrappers override the intended formatting effects of the basic column type you chose, and in consequence you get none of the intended formatting.
- It looks like you're using the `siunitx` package mainly (exclusively?) for its `S` table column type, probably to achieve alignment of the numbers on their decimal markers. If this impression is correct, I recommend you actually use a different column type: `D`, provided by the `dcolumn` package. With the `D` column type, less overhead is required to deal with parentheses and symbols that occur in the numeric columns.
- To avoid getting a gap between the regression coefficient and standard error lines, you may want to place the names of the regressors (in the first column) in a little wrapper that hides the fact that the regressor names occupy two lines from the surrounding `tabular`-like environment. In the code below, I've created a macro called `\narrowtab` for this purpose; feel free to rename it to something else.
- To make the five data columns appear like they're roughly equally wide, it appears to be necessary to abbreviate the labels of Models III and V.

I'm afraid I wasn't able to address your first question since your example code made no reference to that matter.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,dcolumn,caption,amsmath,array,booktabs}
\newcommand{\sym}[1]{{}^{#1}} % correct?
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\narrowtab[2]{%  %% macro to hide depth of its argument from outer tabular
 \ensuremath{\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}@{}}%
     #2 \end{tabular}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{Regression results}
\begin{threeparttable}
%\renewcommand\tabcolsep{1pt}  
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{} p{1in} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{5}{D{,}{,}{2.4}} @{}}
\toprule
& \mc{Model I} & \mc{Model II} & \mc{Model III} & \mc{Model IV} & \mc{Model V} \\
\emph{Afh.\ var.}
& \mc{All partys} & \mc{All partys} & \mc{Soc.\ Dem.} & \mc{Liberal} & \mc{Cons.} \\
\midrule
\emph{Uafh.\ var.} \\
\narrowtab{1in}{Nationalpol.\ effects} & 
0,11\sym{***} & 0,22\sym{*} & 0,33\sym{***} & 0,44\sym{*} & 0,55\sym{***} \\
& (0,11) & (0,22) & (0,33) & (0,44) & (0,55) \\
\addlinespace
\narrowtab{1in}{Economic growth} & 
0,11 & 0,22 & 0,33\sym{***} & 0,44 & 0,55\sym{**}\\
& (0,11) & (0,22) & (0,33) & (0,44) & (0,55) \\
\cmidrule{1-1}
Adjusted R\textsuperscript{2} & 
0,11 & 0,22 & 0,33 & 0,44 & 0,55  \\
N & \mc{111} & \mc{222} & \mc{333} & \mc{444} & \mc{555} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear Mico. Thank you so much for you answer. As you mentioned, I am not helping with the code by intend the lines below Economic growth. The reason why I don't do that, is because I don't know why. I read somewhere, that I should put "/ / /" before "Growth 91-92" Is that the right way of doing it?

Comment: @A.F. - You're welcome. To indent the string "Growth 91-92" a bit, use backslash rather than forward-slash characters: `\ \ \ `. This will insert three "space" characters.

Comment: Is this the right solution: "\ \ \" for my problem?

Comment: @A.F. - What is "right" depends on your objective. Indenting the start of some lines by three spaces may well be OK, but I can't make that decision for you.

Comment: I got following message, when compile my document: "! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (D): `c' used."

Comment: @A.F. - which column type were you trying to use?

Comment: \usepackage{dcolumn}

Comment: I use \usepackage{comma} to my table of content